# getting the full UserProfile profile

Tags: python, django

I am doing this through django

```
$ python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
a = User(username='zoro')
a.get_profile().?
```

what do i type after `get_profile`. to get the full profile instead of typing in one thing like
`a.get_profile().Location` to get just the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.get_profile()` is the full profile (its an instance object of your user profile model). So you can save it in a variable and and use it.

Though if you want to get everything as a python dict you could try `a.get_profile().__dict__`.